# IShellFolder::GetAttributesOf returns unrecognized SFGAOF value

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to find out if a LPITEMIDLIST item in a virtual shell folder is a file or another folder. I am using the call to `IShellFolder::GetAttributesOf` 
In windows 7 it works ok, the returned codes are as they can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). But on windows XP, the uAttrvalue = 1342177378, which is 0x50000062 for directories and 1073741922 (0x40000062) for file, that I cannot find in the SFGAO list.
I simply call it:

```
hr = psfVobj->GetAttributesOf(1, (LPCITEMIDLIST *) &pidlItems, &uAttr);

hr = S_OK //so the function call completed with no errors
```

Comment: [All of those bitfields seem to be defined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  I can only guess you are using an older SDK which does not have some newer definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SFGAO` is a bitmask, it can contain multiple values at one time.

`0x50000062` is binary `1010000000000000000000001100010`, which contains:

> SFGAO_CANMOVE
>   0x00000002 
>   The specified items can be moved.
>
> SFGAO_CANDELETE
>   0x00000020 
>   The specified items can be deleted.
>
> SFGAO_HASPROPSHEET
>   0x00000040 
>   The specified items have property sheets.
>
> SFGAO_FILESYSANCESTOR
>   0x10000000 
>   The specified folders are either file system folders or contain at least one descendant (child, grandchild, or later) that is a file system (SFGAO_FILESYSTEM) folder.
>
> SFGAO_FILESYSTEM
>   0x40000000 
>   The specified folders or files are part of the file system (that is, they are files, directories, or root directories). The parsed names of the items can be assumed to be valid Win32 file system paths. These paths can be either UNC or drive-letter based.

`0x40000062` is binary `1000000000000000000000001100010`, which contains:

> SFGAO_CANMOVE
>   0x00000002
>
> SFGAO_CANDELETE
>   0x00000020
>
> SFGAO_HASPROPSHEET
>   0x00000040
>
> SFGAO_FILESYSTEM
>   0x40000000

That means directories are reporting `SFGAO_FILESYSANCESTOR` and files are not, which makes sense because files are not filesystem ancestors.